# Normal approximation of parameter $p$ of $Bin(n,p)$?

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, estimators

I've seen normal approximation applied for approximating a binomial distribution $B(n,p)$.

However, if one estimates the parameter $p$, then can the parameter $p$ be "normally approximated" just as one can devise a Maximum-Likelihood estimate for $p$?

How is it done?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question. The parameter $p$ is a number in the frequentist setting and thus is non-random. It is the estimate $\hat{p}$ that follows the normal distribution asymptotically. Since $\hat{p}$ is the mle, it converges to the true parameter, $p$, almost surely by the asymptotic properties of the maximum likelihood estimators.

Comment: I want to be able to calculate the normal approximation of $p$.

Comment: Or do you mean that "normally approximating binomial distribution $B(n,p)$" is the equivalent saying of "estimating parameter $p$ of $Bin(n,p)$"?

Comment: @mavavilj There is no normal approximation of $p$ in frequentist statistics.

Comment: I'd expect there to be. One can draw an estimation for $p$, which is the sample proportion $p=\frac{\text{count of success observations}}{\text{all observations}}$. I'm interested in the other approximation ways here.

Comment: You have confused the estimator with the true parameter. You will benefit from studying these concepts again.

Comment: See "Normal Approximations for Counts and Proportions" in http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/binom.htm

Comment: @mavavilj When you stated the distribution to be $Bin(n,p)$, in your question, you made $p$ a parameter (a fixed quantity). You cannot then *also* claim it's a sample proportion. If you use $p$ for the parameter, you should use $\hat{p}$ for the sample estimate. Alternatively, if you want $p$ to be the sample quantity, you should make $\pi$ the symbol for the population quantity (following the convention of Greek symbols for parameters). Either of those is fine (pick one and fix your question) but you can't use $p$ for *two different things*; if you do you will get hopelessly muddled.

Comment: It's the sample quantity that has a sampling distribution. The population quantity is just an unknown number.